# Example of a LCS with a countably compact barrel

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, topological-vector-spaces, locally-convex-spaces

I am self-studying topological vector spaces and I wonder if there is an example of a sequentially complete LCS with a countably compact barrel. I am a complete beginner and really can't think of any.
Thanks all!

Comment: If by countable you mean of cardinality $\leq\aleph_0$, then the space $\{0\}$ looks like it is the only example (it is very hard to have a countable barrel), but I feel like maybe this is not what you are looking for.

Comment: @P.P.Tuong sorry I meant a countably compact barrel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a quite large family of examples which contains many nontrivial spaces. It should be somewhat beginner-friendly as it relies mostly on knowledge of normed spaces rather than general locally convex spaces.

Let $E$ be a Banach space and let $E'_s$ be its weak dual, i.e. $E'_s$ is the locally convex space obtained by endowing the vector space of all continuous linear functionals on $E$ with the topology of pointwise convergence on $E$. The space $E'_s$ can be shown to be sequentially complete and to have a *compact* barrel.

**Proof of sequential completeness**

Let $(x'_n)_{n\in\mathbf N}$ be a Cauchy sequence in $E'_s$. For every $x\in E$, the scalar sequence $(\langle x,x'_n\rangle)_{n\in\mathbf N}$ is Cauchy and thus is convergent. The scalar function $\displaystyle x\mapsto\lim_{n\to\infty}\langle x,x'_n\rangle$ on $E$ is obviously linear and, as a consequence of the [Banach-Steinhaus theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_boundedness_principle), can be seen to be continuous on $E$, meaning it is an element of $E'_s$. This shows that $(x'_n)_{n\in\mathbf N}$ is convergent in $E'_s$.

**Description of a compact barrel**

Let $B=\{x'\in E'_s~|~\forall x\in E,~|\langle x,x'\rangle|\leq\|x\|\}$ (i.e. $B$ is the closed unit ball of the Banach dual of $E$). It is easy to see that $B$ is a barrel of $E'_s$, and the fact that $B$ is compact is a consequence of the [Banach-Alaoglu theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%E2%80%93Alaoglu_theorem).

Comment: Thank you very much!